# jQuery - Count inputs in table row

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to detect if a table row has one or two inputs...

```
<tr class="myoptions">
    <td class="label">
        <label>
            <strong>Options</strong>
        </label>
    </td>
    <td class="value">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" value="test1">
            <label>
                test1
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" value="test1">
            <label>
                test1
            </label>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

How can I count the inputs inside this tr?  Does anybody have an example I can see?

Comment: `$(".value input").length` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var numberOfInputs = $(".myoptions").find("input").length
```

```js
var numberOfInputs = $(".myoptions").find("input").length;

console.log(numberOfInputs);

if (numberOfInputs < 1) {
  console.log("No input");
} else if (numberOfInputs === 1) {
  console.log("One input");
} else if (numberOfInputs === 2) {
  console.log("Two inputs");
} else {
  console.log("More than two inputs");
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="myoptions">
    <td class="label">
      <label>
            <strong>Options</strong>
        </label>
    </td>
    <td class="value">
      <div>
        <input type="radio" value="test1">
        <label>
                test1
            </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" value="test1">
        <label>
                test1
            </label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

One important thing to notice is that you absolutely need a `<table>` element parent since you use `<tr>`, otherwise the browser will wipe out your `<tr>` elements from the DOM - making them unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup for the inputs in the row class `.value`... Which is a strange class name, by the way. Can be confusing...

Then `.length` property will tell you how many there is in the collection.

```js
console.log( $(".value input").length );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr class="myoptions">
    <td class="label">
        <label>
            <strong>Options</strong>
        </label>
    </td>
    <td class="value">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" value="test1">
            <label>
                test1
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" value="test1">
            <label>
                test1
            </label>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```